# Problema con react y webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

estoy haciendo un simple contador de clicks en react con webpack pero obtengo este error y no se como solucionarlo. Adjunto imagenes de mi codigo este es mi package.json
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi componente de react con el error que me da
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi configuracion de webpack 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi configuracion de babel 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradezco si me pueden ayudar. Buen dia.

Answer (score 1):

Estás tratando de declarar una constante dentro del cuerpo de una [clase](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes). Eso no esta permitido. Para que tu metodo funcione, cambiá `handleClick` a:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('Diste click..')
}
```

Ejemplo:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const mensaje = 'Bienvenido!';
    console.log('Diste click..');
    console.log(mensaje);
  }

  render() {
    const titulo = 'Super App'
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{titulo}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>APRETAR</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Puedes declarar variables o constantes dentro de funciones. Pero no en el cuerpo de la clase.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente, el problema es que estas pisando la configuracion de babel en tu `webpack.config.js`, por lo que el set de presets y plugins que especificas en el `.babelrc` no tiene efecto.

Intenta usar esta configuracion:

```js
// ...
rules: [
  // ...
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/),
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: 'babel-loader'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

No hace falta crear una configuracion para webpack, simplemente instala los siguientes paquetes:

```
babel-loader
webpack
webpack-cli 
webpack-dev-server
```

puedes hacer con el siguiente comando:

```
npm i @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-loader webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server
```